# RequireJS loading of modules to be fixed based on ROOT URL + baseUrl + module path

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

Hi i'm using requirejs to just organize my javascript codes into AMD modules, i'm building a non-single page website right now using codeigniter, what i do is i have a default layout html file which i always call to render the dynamic content of the body so my script which call the requirejs and has the data-main attribute is encoded on my layout html page.

```
<script data-main="<?=base_url('assets/js/main.js');?>" src="<?=base_url('assets/js/require.js');?>"></script>
```

and my main.js looks like this.

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: "assets/js",
paths: {
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery',

    bootstrap: 'vendor/bootstrap',

    datatables: 'vendor/jquery.dataTables'

},

shim: {
    jquery: { exports: '$' },
    datatables: { deps: ['jquery'] }
}
});

requirejs(['bootstrap','datatables'], function(){

})
```

so when i type on my url "localhost/ci-project/" it will load the layout page together with the dynamic body. On this scenario it works fine. sicne requirejs will render the path correctly "localhost/ci-project/assets/js/vendor/[js file/module]"

but when i change the URL to say, 'localhost/ci-project/welcome/admin'. what requirejs do to load the modules is concatenate the baseUrl + module path, to the current URL which in this case is 'localhost/ci-project/welcome/admin' and ending result is like this:

'localhost/ci-project/welcome/admin/assets/js/vendor/[module]' which is wrong.

so how can i configure requirejs to always load the from the root url and then concatenate the baseUrl value together with the paths of each modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to solve this is to output the `baseUrl` from a server side variable.

**In your PHP page:**

```
<script>
var require = {
    baseUrl: '<?= base_url(); ?>' // Or whatever outputs the full path to your site root
};
</script>
<script data-main="<?=base_url('assets/js/main.js');?>" src="<?=base_url('assets/js/require.js');?>"></script>
```

Creating a `require` object before RequireJS is loaded allows you to define config options that will be picked up automatically.

Calling `require.config()` again from inside `main.js` is fine, it will just add the additional config options, but be sure to remove `baseUrl` from there.

Answer (score 1):

Simon's answer above helped when I had issues with navigating to routes with parameters - relative paths to base url go wrong. I am using asp .net mvc, but the solution is exactly the same: 
(_Layout.cshtml)

```
<script>
    var require = {
        // by default, load any module IDs from
        baseUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib")'
}
</script>
<script data-main="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/application/app.js")" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib/require.js")"></script>
```